# how to block usage of std::make_shared<T>

Tags: c++, class, c++14, shared-ptr, make-shared

I know I can prevent ordinary heap allocation of custom class and its descendants by making the class's `operator new` private, but is there any way to prevent a user of a library from calling `std::make_shared` on a custom class (or its descendants)?  Apparently, simply making the `operator new` private in a class does not stop it.

Note that I do not want to completely prevent shared pointers from being created by any means, as I intend to still be able to produce a `std::shared_ptr` for my custom class by calling a static generator method, but I still want to prevent others from trying to call `std::make_shared` on my class directly.

EDIT:

To address queries below, my ultimate goal here is a flexible and reusable mechanism for extracting a shared_ptr from a raw pointer. `std::enable_shared_from_this` is regretfully not very friendly when it comes to inheritance and especially multiple inheritance.

Also, because I am intending for this to be used as in a template class using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), it would complicate matters somewhat for the a child class T to need to explicitly make the templated parent class it inherits from a friend so that it can access otherwise private constructors.

Comment: This is a weird design choice. Why do you care if the shared pointer is created for the class or not? Class should not be in a business of their own storage. Perhaps if you can explain your ultimate goal, a better solution can be suggested.

Comment: if only the static generator should create instances then why not private constructor and befriend the generator?

Comment: *"I can prevent ordinary heap allocation of custom class ... by making the class's operator new private"* Can't one circumvent that with `::new`?

Comment: Aren't you allowed to overload the function and mark it as deleted?

Comment: @JVApen How would I do that for a template class without disabling std::make_shared for everything?  Also, I still want to be able to call std::make_shared within the generator function.

Comment: Specialization?

Comment: But how do you specialize for a class whose name you don't know yet?   I want to disallow std::make_shared<N> when N inherits from my custom template class that takes N as a type argument, using a CRTP.

Comment: @markt1964: FYI: "*my ultimate goal here is a flexible and reusable mechanism for extracting a shared_ptr from a raw pointer*" If that is an operation which you do so often that you need a "flexible and reusable mechanism" for it, *especially* one more powerful than the standard mechanism, then your design is not in a good place. Code which randomly claims ownership of an object which they were *not initially given ownership over* should usually be considered a code smell. Not necessarily wrong, just not good.

Comment: No more smell than what is produced by `std::enable_shared_from_this` in the first place.  And, as I said, that particular mechanism by itself is not ideally suited for cases where you may have a complex inheritance tree, and shared pointers might be used at any and every level.

Comment: @markt1964: "*No more smell than what is produced by `std::enable_shared_from_this` in the first place.*" Yes. Which is why the use of that mechanism should be strictly controlled. It's to be used where *essential*, not by default. Using it in a CRTP base class, for example, is *absolutely* the wrong way to go. A CRTP base class has no right to claim ownership of the derived instance, let alone to give that ownership to others. "*shared pointers might be used at any and every level*" That sounds like you're treating shared pointers like C++ garbage collection, when they very much are not.

Comment: @NicolBolas If `std::enable_shared_from_this were` more friendly to inheritance, and particularly multiple inheritance, I'd agree. The problem is that if something is to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, it needs to happen exactly once on the inheritance tree, and this can be hard to control when the inheritance tree gets too complicated. The mechanism I have coded so far works, but does not currently prevent a user from calling `std::make_shared` on a class directly, which will break the assumption my code makes that shared pointers are generated by the generator function.

Comment: @markt1964 `enable_shared_from_this` is fundamentally a hack, and a very dirty one at that. It works only with SI, public (even though the class might consider it an implementation detail) and doesn't work for a member subobject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking user heap allocation of a type `T` is not actually a thing you can do in C++. At least, not so long as they can create `T`s. Even if you manage to forbid `make_shared<T>`, your user can still do this:

```
unique_ptr opt = new optional<T>;
opt->emplace(...);
```

The `T` inside of `*opt` is definitely on the heap. Any number of other similar gymnastics can achieve the same effect. You can even call `make_shared<optional<T>>`, with the `in_place` parameters.

So long as `T` has publicly accessible constructors, or there is any publicly accessible way of constructing a `T` that returns a prvalue of it, users can find ways to store that `T` on the heap.

So the only way to prevent this is to make all of your constructors private (whether directly with `private` or a `private` key type or whatever other mechanism you want) and only provide publicly accessible functions that return `shared_ptr<T>`s.

Outside of macros, there is no C++ mechanism that just causes a type to work this way. It must be done individually, for each type that you want to work this way.

Answer (score 6):

This is not specific for `std::shared_ptr`, but you can make the constructor private and that way force all instances of the class to get generated from your static method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
    private:
    Foo() = default;

    public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> make() {
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
    }
};

int main() {
    //Foo f1;
    //auto f2 = std::make_shared<Foo>(); 
    //above does not work since the constructor is private
    auto h = Foo::make();
}
```

You can also use deduplicators suggestion and use a private key to make the constructor inaccessible outside of the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
    private:
    struct FooKey {};

    public:
    Foo(FooKey) {};

    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> make() {
        return std::make_shared<Foo>(FooKey{});
    }
};

int main() {
    //Foo f1{Foo::FooKey{}};
    //auto f2 = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo::FooKey{}); 
    //above does not work since Foo::FooKey is private
    auto h = Foo::make();
}
```

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Type mismatch.

Comment: Better use an empty trivial type as a key, so `std::make_shared()` can be used.

Comment: The existence of placement `new` means that controlling access to the constructor (this solution) is probably the only way to reliably take control of how and when your instance is created.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's an option. Added since the question mentions `make_shared`.

Comment: This is interesting, but not readily estensible if I want to also inherit from the class.  The child class will need to always know to call the parent class with an otherwise private (or protected) argument, and if other constructors are needed, that extra arg will have to prefix every one of them.  It will, I'm afraid, start to look ugly after more than 3 or 4 classes are created.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are better solutions to the problem. But, if you're trying to not let the make_shared make new instance of your class, maybe this is helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    void * operator new(size_t size) {}
};

template<> shared_ptr<A> make_shared() {
    cout << "this was called.\n";
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    shared_ptr<A> p = make_shared<A>(a);
    shared_ptr<A> q = make_shared<A>();
    cout << "p: " << p << endl;
    cout << "q: " << q << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

'p' gets a object address while 'q' doesn't.

Note: requires -fpermissive option in the compiler.